# How to plot clusters produced by KMeans using matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, k-means

I used KMeans for clustering as shown below, but I don't know to plot my clusters in a scatter plot.
[image] 
Or like This plot too
[image]
My code is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score

documents = ["This little kitty came to play when I was eating at a restaurant.",
             "Merley has the best squooshy kitten belly.",
             "Google Translate app is incredible.",
             "If you open 100 tab in google you get a smileyface.",
             "Best cat photo I've ever taken.",
             "Climbing ninja cat.",
             "Impressed with google map feedback.",
             "Key promoter extension for Google Chrome."]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

true_k = 2
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you might be looking to do something like this? I plotted the data, coloring by label, after converting to cluster distance space.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score
import pandas as pd

documents = ["This little kitty came to play when I was eating at a restaurant.",
             "Merley has the best squooshy kitten belly.",
             "Google Translate app is incredible.",
             "If you open 100 tab in google you get a smileyface.",
             "Best cat photo I've ever taken.",
             "Climbing ninja cat.",
             "Impressed with google map feedback.",
             "Key promoter extension for Google Chrome."]

df = pd.DataFrame(documents) # read in your data with pd.read_csv or if in list form like above do this
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df[0].values.astype('U')) # make sure you have unicode strings [0] is the column of the sentences


true_k = 2
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=2000, n_init=20)
Xt = model.fit_transform(X)


  # things with tf-idf score 
X = X.toarray()
fns =  np.array(vectorizer.get_feature_names()) # feature names/ordered by index

# retrieve labels with max score
labels = model.labels_ 
d = []
for n in sorted(np.unique(labels)):
    t = X[(labels == n)].sum(axis=0) #max tf/idf score cumulative/cluster
    words = fns[t == t.max()]
    d.append(",".join(words))

t = Xt.T # cluster distance space X transpose to be plotted with mpl

### plot the clusters
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

cluster_color_dict = {0:'purple', 1 :'blue'} # change these to desired colors
for i in range(len(t[0])):

    ax.scatter(t[0][i], t[1][i], c= cluster_color_dict[labels[i]], edgecolors='grey', lw = 0.5, s = 200)

p1 = [] # legend patches 
for i in range(2):
    print i
    h = ax.scatter([],[], c= cluster_color_dict[i], 
                    edgecolors= 'grey', lw = 0.5, s = 80, label = d[i]) 
    p1.append(h)

l1 = ax.legend(handles = p1, title= 'cluster',  bbox_to_anchor = (1,1), loc = 'upper left')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, can you have a look on my original post, i added 2 photos with plots that i am tring to do ..

Comment: I edited my answer to include retrieving the feature names that had highest cumulative scores to name the clusters (google, cat) , is this more like what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you so much .. How can i do to remove the countour representig by sentences number? please ?? My real data contains 4000 lines, i choose to put just 6  lines .

Comment: sure! I'll update it, just need to remove edgecoloring in ax.scatter and comment out adding the second legend at the bottom

Comment: Thank you so much ... I want to add also colorCluster 1 = purprle colorCluster = Blue for better display ..Thank youu

Comment: Ok, I updated as you mentioned so you should be able to easily play with this to suit your needs, if you plot a lot of points you may need to shrink the points (by changing s = 80), if this answers your question please accept :)

Comment: Thank you but i got this error .. ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.

Comment: from where in the traceback? need more info to understand how your real implementation differs from this test case

Comment: Actually I think I understand the error, possibly comes from vectorizer, basically your input document isn't all strings

Comment: I have updated it to include a step, before vectorizer, where the data is read into a pandas dataframe and converted to unicode string format, I think that should solve it.  Note that if you are reading in your data to pandas, you can use pd.read_csv here instead.